# Does a solution for this integral even exists? $I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(a+\sin(x))dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Some time ago I computed $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(1+\sin(x))dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(1-\sin(x))dx$, which suggested to tackle the more general case:
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(a+\sin(x))dx$$
with $a>0$. I wasn't able to solve it. I approached it whith Feynman technique: consider $I$ as $I(a)$, and so $\frac{dI}{da}=\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{1}{a+\sin(x)}dx$, which evaluates with standard calculus to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}}$. Unfortunately seems like this result cannot be integrated with respect to $a$, so I got stuck. Anyone knows a solution?

Notes:

Clearly $I=\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(a+\sin(x))dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(a+\cos(x))dx$.

Here are the results I got for the first two integrals if it can help:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(1+\sin(x))dx=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)\hspace{1cm}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(1-\sin(x))dx=-2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$$
where G is Catalan constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{1+t^2}{2t}$ then $da=\frac{t^2-1}{2t^2}dt$ and
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}}\,da
&=
\int\frac{4t}{t^2-1}\arctan\big({\frac{t-1}{t+1}}\big)\frac{t^2-1}{2t^2}\,dt\\
&=2\int\frac{1}{t}\arctan\big({\frac{t-1}{t+1}}\big)\,dt\\
&=
2\int\frac{1}{t}\left(\arctan (t)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,dt
\\
&=
2\int\frac{1}{t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\,dt-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(t)\\
&=
2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(t)+c.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, since $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(1+\sin(x))dx=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$, for $a\geq 1$,
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(a+\sin(x))dx=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2t)$$
with $t=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}$. Note that the series, which has no closed formula, is related to the [Legendre chi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function) (see also Claude Leibovici's answer).

Comment: Thank you, I have two questions: solving back for $a$ I get $t=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}$. Should I pick the positive or negative? And also, the last series has no closed form?

Comment: Yes, the last series has no closed form. Recall that $G=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k }{(2k+1)^2}$

Comment: Nice way. Notice that the summation is just $\frac{1}{4} t \Phi \left(-t^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici what is the name of the function you mention?

Comment: @Zima. $\Phi(.)$ is   the Lerch transcendent function.

Answer (score 4):

Even the antiderivative exists in terms of polylogarithm functions (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BLog%5Ba%2BSin%5Bx%5D%5D%2Cx%5D)).
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\log(a+\sin(x))\,dx$$ $$I=\frac 1a+\frac{\pi  }{2} \log \left( \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}2\right)+
\frac{2}{9 a^3}\,\,
   _3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{1}{a^
   2}\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\log(a-\sin(x))\,dx$$
$$J=-\frac 1a+\frac{\pi  }{2} \log \left( \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}2\right)-\frac{2}{9 a^3}\,\,
   _3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$

**Edit**

Notice that
$$\,_3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=1+\frac{12}{25 a^2}+\frac{72}{245 a^4}+\frac{64}{315
   a^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^8}\right)$$ which is in a relative error of $0.01$% for $a=2.51$ and $0.001$% for $a=3.34$

Answer (score 1):

Using series
$$\log(a+\sin(x))=\log(a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{\sin ^n(x)}{a^n \,n}$$
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sin ^n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \,\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}$$
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\log(a+\sin(x))\,dx$$ $$I=\frac \pi 2 \log(a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n^2\, a^n\,
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$

$$I=\frac{\pi  }{2} \log \left( \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}2\right)+
\frac{1}{a}\,\,
   \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{
   a^2}\right)$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I wrote it in my first answer for the antiderivative. Cheers :-)

Comment: clear derivation thank you